# Why doesn't the compiler optimize out these unreachable instructions?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, assembly, clang

Given this code:

```
int x;

int a (int b) {
    b = a (b);
    b += x;
    return b;
}
```

why does GCC return this output (Intel Syntax): http://goo.gl/8D32F1 - Godbolt's GCC Explorer

```
a:
    sub rsp, 8
    call    a
    mov edx, DWORD PTR x[rip]
    add rsp, 8
    lea eax, [rax+rdx*8]
    add eax, edx
    ret
```

and Clang return this output (AT&T Syntax): http://goo.gl/Zz2rKA - Godbolt's Clang Explorer

```
a:                                      # @a
    pushq   %rax
    callq   a
    addl    x(%rip), %eax
    popq    %rdx
    ret
```

when part of the code is clearly unreachable? Since the very first statement of the function is

```
b = a (b);
```

the function will forever keep calling itself recursively (until the stack overflows and you get a segfault). This means that you will never go beyond that line, and therefore, the rest of the code is unreachable. Reachability optimization should in theory remove the code, correct?

---

Both compilers were running on x64 and with the following flags

- `-O3` - max optimization
- `-march=native` - [unnecessary] use machine specific optimizations when possible
- `-x c` - assume input language  is C

---

I was thinking that they should have returned something more along the lines (pun intended) of this:

GCC (Intel Syntax):

```
a:
.L1:
    jmp .L1
```

Clang (AT&T Syntax):

```
a:
.LBB0_1:
    jmp .LBB0_1
```

note: these samples were written by hand from memory of previous observations and may be incorrect.

---

So overall, why don't either of the compilers collapse the function into a single recursive jump due to the rest of the code being unreachable?

---

## EDIT:

### Response to Jack's comment on semantic equivalence:

For the following code:

```
int j (int x) {
    while (1) {};
    x++;
    return x;
}
```

GCC returns: http://goo.gl/CYSUW2

```
j:
.L2:
    jmp .L2
```

Clang returns:

```
j:                                      # @j
.LBB0_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    jmp .LBB0_1
```

---

### Response to Adam's comment on blowing out the stack:

For this code:

```
int r (int x) {
    return r (x);
}
```

GCC generates a recursive jump: http://goo.gl/eWo2Nb

```
r:
.L2:
    jmp .L2
```

Clang returns cleanly early: http://goo.gl/CVJKiZ

```
r:                                      # @r
    ret
```

Comment: Your expected result is not the same as the compiled code. The compiled code will overflow the stack, your jumps will not. Therefore the compiler would be changing the behavior of the program by doing your optimization.

Comment: @Adam: Which is OK because blowing the stack is undefined behaviour.

Comment: A compiler is under no obligation to optimize away unreachable code, especially when it's almost certainly a bug situation.

Comment: @tmyklebu - Erm ... I wouldn't have said that silently converting a broken method to a different but unbroken method was "OK".  Even if the brokenness involved undefined behaviour.  Undefined behaviour is not an excuse for the compiler to do whatever it wants.

Comment: @StephenC: But it is an excuse for the compiler to do whatever it wants.  Silently converting "blow the stack" into "loop forever" is totally OK.

Comment: @HotLicks - Indeed, busting a gut to optimize situations involving buggy / pathological code is almost certainly a waste of the compiler writer's effort.  To the OP - what would be the *point* of the optimization ... given that the code clearly won't work in either case.

Comment: @StephenC: There is no point.  However, examining and understanding pointless cases like this can shed light on what the compiler will do in nontrivial situations.  (Here, for instance, you might learn about limitations to gcc's and clang's dead code elimination that you didn't know before, and how to deal with them.)

Comment: Re your update showing tail-call elimination.  You are missing the point that that optimization CANNOT be performed on the original code ... because it is not a tail call.  (Even ignoring that the original example does not terminate.)

Comment: From a technical standpoint, and speaking as a once optimizer designer, unless the compiler was set up to recognize/optimize recursion it would not have noticed that the call was a recursive one, and hence would not have figured out the following code was unreachable.  And even when recursion was being observed, there would be no merit in dealing with the above case.

Comment: @tmyklebu - I don't see how you can make a logical inference.  At best, you can treat this as a clue.  The only way to understand what is really going on is to examine the respective optimizer source code.  And even if you are going to treat this as "just a clue", it is a pretty unreliable clue given that this is not someone that you would expect them to try to get right.  (See HotLick's last comment ...)

Comment: @StephenC there isn't any particular point - I'm just curious, but I must say I agree with tmykylebu's last comment.

Comment: @haneefmubarak - Whatever ... It might give you a more clear mental model, but there is nothing in the "evidence" of this example to say that your clarity is actually accurate.

Comment: The code has undefined behaviour because it violates the constraints of 1.10/27 (it doesn't terminate, essentially). So it doesn't really matter what the compilers do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compilers you're using probably implement data flow analysis only at the block level within a single function frame, not taking into consideration recursion. (Or perhaps, only interesting recursion, namely tail recursion.)  Since the recursive call isn't a tail call, it isn't interesting from an optimization point of view.

Your function has a problem: the way it is compiled, it blows up the stack. It is compiled that way because the call isn't a tail call; it is not a legitimate optimization to treat it as one.

The call could be considered a "pseudo tail call" on grounds that that the code after the call is never invoked, and so if we remove that code, then the recursive call is the last thing which the function does.  Then we could reduce the stack-blowing code to a mere infinite loop. This cannot really be called an optimization, though; it's the replacement of one bug manifestation by a different bug manifestation.

Comment: Hmm.  My daft question:  Why does dead code elimination decide the stuff after the recursive call is live, though?

Comment: @tmyklebu - because it is ungrammatical, and difficult to parse.  Change "decide" to "decide that" and the meaning becomes more clear.

Comment: @tmyklebu - The answer is that it doesn't decide that it is alive.  Rather, it fails to notice that it is dead.

Comment: @StephenC: That would indeed improve the comment.  Unfortunately, it's too late for me to fix it.

Comment: For determining dead code, the compiler is analyzing a local graph of the program that doesn't span across function calls.

Comment: @Kaz: OK, that pretty much nails it then.  (I thought interprocedural everything was the norm these days, but I guess inlining obviates the need for analysis across function boundaries in a lot of cases.)